# ActiveMQ one queue multi consumers

Tags: java, spring-integration, activemq-classic, spring-integration-dsl

I understand that there are a lot of similar questions, but I couldn't find the correct answer.

I'm using a few microservices that have to listens to a single ActiveMQ Queue.
Every microservice use a Spring Integration 5 with DSL Messaging flow.
Is there any way how to listen to a single Queue with multiple consumers?

I've tried an approach with CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE mode, but it doesn't work well for me, every message is delivered to every specific consumer, when rollback happens - message redeliveries to the same consumer.

Unfortunately, I cannot use VirtualDestinations or Topics,  because ActiveMQ broker configuration is placed to the customer-side and policies are restricted to do any configuration changes.

Comment: Your question is not clear; are you sure it's a Queue? With a Queue, only one consumer gets each message; with a Topic all consumers get a copy. When rolling back, there is no guarantee the same consumer will get the redelivery. Add more information, configuration etc.

Comment: Totally agree @Garry Russel. The question is tricky. I should have closed this question. It is no longer valid. 
Thank you for your support!